# how to change dynamic button background color

Tags: button, dynamic, swift, colors, background

I have programmatically created buttons, want to change color when button clicked, For example if a button clicked change the color to red, another button clicked means change back to default

I created button using

```
 for var i=0 ;i<=8;i++{
 var button = UIButton(..)
 ........... blah blah......

button.addTarget(..,action:"buttonsClick",...)

}

 fun buttonsClick(sender:UIButton){
    // here how to identify which button is clicked and change color to red if another is clicked means change to default color
    var tagnum = sender.tag

    }
```

Or another solution available for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that output from another discussion in the stackoverflow

create a function

func Changecolor(sender:UIButton){

if sender.backgroundColor == UICcolor.graycolor() {

sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.redcolor()

}
else
{

sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.graycolor()

}

This function called in

button.addTarget(blah,selector:"Changecolor:",forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.AllEvents)